# Converting String to Timestamp in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to convert this string '1/17/2022, 11:59 PM' into timestamp (Like "01/17/2022 11:59:00 PM") in BigQuery.

Edit: timestamp 2022/01/17 23:59:00 UTC

I have tried with PARSE_DATE function but it did not allow me to convert string. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: "01/17/2022 11:59:00 PM" is not a timestamp type, but a string type with another format.
You just want to re-format it ?

Comment: Oops sorry. I meant timestamp in the standard format (ignore my example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to use below query.

```sql
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y, %I:%M %p', '1/17/2022, 11:59 PM') ts
```

[image]

Comment: for the meaning of each format element, you can check here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements